# Regex for Arrays within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an array of arrays (call the outer array arr1) with numerous values which are all inner arrays. I am trying to validate that the inner arrays have the following format for its elements with arr1[1] provided as an example (the other elements of arr1, i.e. arr1[2], arr1[3], arr1[4], etc. are of the same format

```
arr1[1] = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']:

item 1 - "abcdef" (variable number of letters)
item 2 - "abcdef" (variable number of letters)
item 3 - "abcdef" (variable number of letters) OR "abcdef asdf" (variable number of letters separated by one whitespace character)    
item 4 - "12345678" (eight digits)
item 5 - "123 456 7890" (telephone number with 3 digits followed by 3 digits followed by 4 digits with two whitespace characters as shown)
```

Here is a snippet of what I have so far (not sure how the second line works - got it from a different SO thread):

```
function f(s) {
  var s2 = (""+s).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var m = s2.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Also, your inner arrays - `["item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"]` - this is an array with 1 item in it (a long string), is this what you've actually got, or is it something different?

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if its correct so that others can get help out of it.

Comment: James - you interpreted it correctly. Each inner array features a long string with components separated by commas. I want to use regex on the comma-separated components

Comment: Hi - the values I'm passing are objects. Am I able to perform regex on an item with typeof() = object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
item 1 - \w+ (variable number of letters)
item 2 - \w+ (variable number of letters)
item 3 - \w+(?:\s\w+)? (variable number of letters) OR 
                         (variable number of letters 
                          separated by one whitespace character)    
item 4 - \d{8} (eight digits)
item 5 - (?:\d{3}\s){2}\d{4} (telephone number with 3 digits 
                              followed by 3 digits followed by 4 
                              digits with two whitespace characters as shown)
```

**EDIT:** You can use `^\w+?,\s\w+?,\s\w+(?:\s\w+)?,\s\d{8},\s(?:\d{3}\s){2}\d{4}$` to directly validate the string.

Ex:

```
function validateStr(str) {
  return (/^\[\s'\w+?',\s'\w+?',\s'\w+(?:\s\w+)?',\s'\d{8}',\s'(?:\d{3}\s){2}\d{4}'\s\]$/).test(str);
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer for you(I did not notice the update). Combine it with my answer where you have different functions to check different regular expressions. Pass in a parameter and verify if the parameter satisfies the expression or not. It should work for you.

Comment: Can you provide a little more guidance on how to implement that into this specific case? James Thorpe's comments above are correctly interpreting my question

Comment: It is returning false for this:

[ 'abaa', 'aba', 'dffdfd', '12345678', '123 456 0876' ]

Does that have to do with the '' marks?

Comment: See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR7eE8/1).. problem could be with spaces or quotes.. am i using correct inputs that you are getting?

Comment: Updated for quotes and brackets.. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR7eE8/2).. You can change as required..

Comment: Do the values in the string need to be a certain type of format? I am getting false when I run the demo on values that should be passing

Comment: Yes.. Regex is pattern matching.. So input strings should always be in certain format..

Comment: Hi - the values I'm passing are objects. Is there a simple way to convert each element to  a string?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like -

```
function checkTelephone(s) {
      return (/^(\d{3})\s(\d{3})\s(\d{4})$/).test(s);
}
```

This function returns false if the string does not match the telephone regular expression.